# Java ImageProcessing "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" Error

Tags: java, netbeans, project, bufferedimage

I am creating an ImageProcessing project on NetbeansIDE. I get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` error a function of program. I don't
understand the cause of error. I read similar topic, but I couldn't
find a solution. I give the function. Please help me.

I want to detect eyes and nose in a face image. Firstly save all pixel brightness in horizontal and vertical histogram arrays. Then, I scan arrays and find brightest pixel. Finally, I paint black the pixels.

My English is not perfect, so I'm sorry.

```
public BufferedImage detectHistograms(BufferedImage resim){        
        int[] horizontalHistogram = new int[resim.getWidth()];
        int[] verticalHistogram = new int[resim.getHeight()];

        //first assigment to histogram arrays
        for(int i=0; i<=horizontalHistogram.length-1; i++){
            horizontalHistogram[i]=0;
            verticalHistogram[i]=0;
        }

        //take the brightness values of the image
        for(int i=0; i<=resim.getHeight()-1; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<=resim.getWidth()-1; j++){
                horizontalHistogram[i] += resim.getRGB(j, i);
                verticalHistogram[j] += resim.getRGB(j, i);
            }
        }

        //detect max vertical and horizontal histograms
        int araDegiskenYatay = 0;
        int araDegiskenDikey = 0;
        int maxYatayPiksel = 0;
        int maxDikeyPiksel = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<=horizontalHistogram.length-1; i++){
            if(horizontalHistogram[i] > araDegiskenYatay){
                araDegiskenYatay = horizontalHistogram[i];
                maxYatayPiksel = i;
            }
        }
        for(int i=0; i<=verticalHistogram.length-1; i++){
            if(horizontalHistogram[i] > araDegiskenDikey){
                araDegiskenDikey = verticalHistogram[i];
                maxDikeyPiksel = i;
            }
        }

        //paint black of detect max and min histogram pixels
        Color newColor = new Color(0,0,0);
        for(int i=0; i<=resim.getWidth()-1; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<=resim.getHeight()-1; j++){
                resim.setRGB(maxYatayPiksel, maxDikeyPiksel,newColor.getRGB() );
            }
        }

        return resim;
    }
```

Comment: Where does the exception occur? You should add the stack trace to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your horizontalHistogram[] is initialized with the  resim.getWidth() but in the birightnes loop your indexes are bound by resim.getHeight().

Same for the vertical. So if your height != width you will access one of the arrays outside the bounds.

Comment: I did what you said but result didn't change

Comment: stacktrace will tell you where you have your error. Your second for loop in detecting max also has the indexes boundaries messed up.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0; i<=horizontalHistogram.length-1; i++){
        horizontalHistogram[i]=0;
    }
 for(int i=0; i<=verticalHistogram.length-1; i++){
        verticalHistogram[i]=0;
    }
```

Comment: I would add some explanation for why this is the correct solution. I didn't downvote you, but I'm guessing that's why you got the downvote.

Comment: Sorry , I thought this is enough for solve problem :) thanx for your (@b4hand) explanation, I had no idea why this was downvoted.
Thanks @MuhammedYusufTaşkesenligil

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. My image label size is 150*150, but I was trying to give a bigger picture. Now, I give a 150*150 picture and no error. Thank you